# Do custom HTML elements inherit parent CSS styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-controls

When creating custom elements in HTML, does the child tag inherit the parent's CSS styles?

Here is my test case, from Chrome:

```
var h1bProto = document.registerElement ('h1-b', 
{
  prototype: Object.create (HTMLHeadingElement.prototype),
  extends: "h1"
});
```

When I append a child using the new h1bProto it generates an H1 tag with is="h1-b", example below:

```
var node = document.body.appendChild (new hibProto());
node.textContent = "Hello";

<h1 is="h1-b">Hello</h1>
```

## Hello

This gives me the parents CSS styles.  However, if I add a node by creating the element first, then appending the node, the code looks like this:

```
var node = document.createElement ("h1-b");
node.textContent = "Hello";
document.body.appendChild (node);

<h1-b>Hello</h1-b>
```

Hello

Am I missing something, or do children not inherit the parent's CSS styles? If they don't, then is the best work around to use the Shadow DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [W3 spec you aren't going crazy](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#custom-elements-customized-builtin-example)!

> Trying to use a customized built-in element as an autonomous custom
>   element will not work; that is, Click
>   me? will simply create an HTMLElement with no special
>   behaviour.

Aka, in your example making a tag with `<h1-b>` will not apply the styling or behavior of an `<h1>` tag. Instead you must create an `<h1>` tag with the is attribute set to the name of your custom element. The section I linked you to in the spec actually does a great job explaining how to go about creating the tag.

All in all, you just need to make your element like so:

```
document.createElement("h1", { is: "h1-b" });
```

One reason that comes to mind for this is that most bots don't parse your javascript. As a result they would have a challenge to figure out what the elements in your dom really are. Imagine how much your seo would tank if a bot didn't realize that your `<h1-b>` elements were really `<h1>` elements!

Comment: Uhrm ... SEO's ... Ya, Agree! =)

Comment: @E Net Arch. If this answered your question could you mark it as your answer? If not could you let us know why?

Comment: After thinking about how custom Ht ML tags might interfere with SEO, I have to disagree.  However, I'm making your case here for others to understand.  The P tag helps bots understand where TEXT is located, vs a custom tag which embeds data in the tags property values.  And, this is different from XML, which uses name value pair, which can be transformed into HTML.  All of which, broadens my topic, and also takes it off topic.

Comment: While this answer does address the problem .... this is the default behavior .. I was hoping that others would provide their perspectives. Since, many other developers I've talked with have used custom tags in their documents.  However, their perspectives would only address the SEO issue, which technically is off topic.

Comment: Ah, if it's the SEO part that you take issue with, I'd be happy to remove that part of my answer (since it is just conjecture). We could then make another SO post and I'd be happy to paste my conjecture there as an answer. This is a bit wordy but maybe a question along the lines of: "why does the W3 spec prevent you from using a customized built-in element as an autonomous custom element". That way we keep this answer focused and the other post will get some good attention.