# Custom HTML elements defined in JS not inheriting parent element styles

Tags: javascript, css, shadow-dom, custom-element, css-counter

I am trying to create two new custom HTML elements `step-list` and `step-item` which will work similar to `ol` and `li` items and will create an ordered list with any single-digit numbers preceded by a `0`.

I'm trying to accomplish this using CSS `counter-reset` and `counter-increment`, and `customElements.define()`

The issue I'm experiencing is that even though I add `counter-reset: steps 0` to the `step-list` element and `counter-increment: steps` to the `step-list` item, every single one renders as `01`, instead of `01`, `02`, `03`, etc.

> **Note:** I also want to clarify in advance that this question is NOT a duplicate to this question ([Do custom HTML elements inherit parent CSS styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386066/do-custom-html-elements-inherit-parent-css-styles)), as that question is in regards to inheriting styles of the element the new custom elements extends.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
class StepList extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const style = document.createElement('style');
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
        // shadowRoot.innerHTML += this.innerHTML;
        Array.from(this.children).forEach(child => shadowRoot.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true)));
        style.textContent = `:host(step-list) { counter-reset: steps ${Number(this.getAttribute('start')) || 0}; --step: ${this.hasAttribute('step') && !isNaN(this.getAttribute('step')) ? Number(this.getAttribute('step')) : 1}; }`;
    }
}
customElements.define('step-list', StepList);
class StepItem extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const style = document.createElement('style');
        const content = document.createElement('div');
        content.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
        shadowRoot.appendChild(content);
        style.textContent = `
            :host::before { counter-increment: steps 1; content: "0" counter(steps); }
            :host:nth-child(n+10)::before { counter-increment: steps var(--step, 1); content: counter(steps); }
        `;
    }
}
customElements.define('step-item', StepItem);
```

```html
<step-list>
    <step-item>Testing</step-item>
    <step-item>Testing</step-item>
    <step-item>Testing</step-item>
    <step-item>Testing</step-item>
    <step-item>Testing</step-item>
    <step-item>Testing</step-item>
    <step-item>Testing</step-item>
    <step-item>Testing</step-item>
    <step-item>Testing</step-item>
    <step-item>Testing</step-item>
</step-list>
```

Comment: I think that's the point of using shadow DOM.